# getting back to (bookmarking) a part of YouTube playlist

Tags: bookmarks, youtube

I am watching a Russian video blogger (sewing-related) who has thousands of videos, and a few of them are mini-series on how to make something. She often refers to the older videos in the newer ones. Because of that I am watching them from the oldest to newest, so I need to scroll through the hundreds of watched videos to get to the ones I haven't watched yet. Is there a way to manage a list of thousands of videos? Ideally I want to bookmark a part of the long scrolling page that I need to get to. I know I can create my own playlists, but this seems like even more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, after some experimentation, the only way I found to do this is through setting up a developer profile and using YouTube API. Then you can list all the videos in a channel in .csv format and navigate the channel that way.

I can't believe that YouTube does not give you a way to easily get to the middle of 2000+ videos playlist. The infinite scolling should be outlawed. I never liked it.

Full answer with a mini-app to get .csv file is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel

The app itself - https://answerquest.github.io/youtube-all-vids-info.html

Once you get your API key, you will need the channel ID and then the playlist ID which is almost the same as channel ID (replace the second letter C in channel ID with U).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do that if your goal is to stream videos but if you have enough storage space to download the files then you can always use an app like [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template) to download all the videos in the playlist and use the `upload_date` option to format the output file name so that it starts with the date that the video was uploaded. Then you just sort your file manager by file name and you will have a sorted playlist.